# Heroku can't find ExpressJS/Knex migrations

Tags: postgresql, express, heroku, knex.js

I have an Express.js api that works locally, using Postgresql via Knex/SQL queries.

I am trying to deploy to Heroku, however, when I attempt to migrate the DB I get the error that Heroku can't find the migration files.

Specifically, when I run the migration it throws:

> Using environment: production Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, scandir '/app/migrations'

My migrations are located at my_app/db/migrations. The app folder mentioned in the error does not exist. Trying to figure out how to point to the correct folder.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "writerboard-express-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "dariusgoore <dariusgoore@gmail.com> (dariusgoore.com)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.19.3",
    "objection": "^1.6.9",
    "objection-password": "^2.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

My knexfile (myapp/knexfile.js):

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: "../.env" });

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'writerboard_dev', // update with env var
      user:     'dariusgoore' // update with env var
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
      directory: './db/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './db/seeds'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    },
    ssl: true
  }

};
```

here is the server log from heroku:

```
2019-09-16T14:25:00.251226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2019-09-16T14:25:00.063523+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user dariusgoore@gmail.com
2019-09-16T14:25:00.063523+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b697b243 by user dariusgoore@gmail.com
2019-09-16T14:25:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-09-16T14:25:03.700742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2019-09-16T14:25:08.369304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-09-16T14:25:07.885086+00:00 app[web.1]: Running on localhost:58146
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, the answer was in the knexfile.js.  Needed to set the migrations directory for production.